# floating boxes with different heights: jquery plugin to float them with specific margin?

Tags: jquery, css, css-float

hey guys,
i'm almost sure that i've stumbled across a plugin like that.

i have multiple widgets in my footer that are all floated:right. All those widgets have different sizes and so the floating doesn't properly work. They get floated but you can imagine what it looks like: a lot of different spaces and just ugly.

I'm looking for a jquery plugin to solve this problem so that all those boxes kind of slide to the margin of the next box.

i hope my explanation is not to complex. any idea how that plugin is called?

thank you

Comment: Can you provide us with a code example? http://jsfiddle.om

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tkBZE/ Exactly like this. i want the green box to slide up to 10px underneath the red one and the grey one should slide up as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David Desandro's jQuery Masonry plugin will do just the trick.

http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/